# 404 errors being redirected to the homepage instead of custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have a site hosted on an Apache server. I have created some custom error pages and the following text at the top of my `.htaccess file`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.html

ErrorDocument 500 500.html

ErrorDocument 401 401.html
```

I have also tried,

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
```

Both the htaccess file and the custom pages are in the root directory of the server.
The problem is that when I enter a garbage url (where I would expect to see my custom 404 page) I'm simply being redirected to my index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if your server is properly set up to parse and process .htaccess files in the first place (i.e., check if `AllowOverride` + `AccessFileName` directives are correct). For example, write some stuff in that you know will work and look if it actually gets executed (like a ridiculous rewrite rule). Also, look up your httpd log files for errors.

If it does get executed properly, the problem might be that your server is setup not to allow all kinds of overrides with .htaccess files. Your syntax however, is basically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what you are suggesting sounds like having access to the server configuration in some manner, and I'm afraid I don't. However I am aware that the wordpress blog I have installed uses rewrite rules successfully.

Comment: Is it possible that the htaccess file you are currently using is redirecting any requests to the index file? Wordpress might redirect anything, even if it's total garbage to the index.php, and expects your php files to handle any kind of 404 errors manually.

Comment: Hey thanks! I removed all the wordpress lines and the 404 page was delivered as expected.... I don't suppose you know how I can stop Wordpress breaking it? I can Google it, I just thought I would ask if you don't mind :)

Comment: You can't really do that as far as I am concerned, because wordpress simply needs that in order to work. As I said, you have to modify the index.php or some other code to manually check for 404 errors (actually, a proper Wordpress installation should handle that by itself). The reason is simple: Wordpress (and most other software) uses a "virtual" file structure, therefore you cannot check if files pysically exists on the harddisk, you need to check if it _would_ exist in your _virtual_ file concepts.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I'll investigate the php method. Cheers.